# Pipe character is being skipped in java string

Tags: java, linux, string, special-characters

I have a java architecture which accepts linux command as a string, which run on a remote linux machine and returns the output.

The command as a string is working for these single commands such as

```
cat filename
grep <string> filename
```

But the command is not executing properly when I pass it a with pipe such as this one

```
cat filename | grep string
```

The command is being sent as a java string. I tried to pipe with `\\` (like this `\\|` ) but with no success.

Any possible solution ?

Ps: The architecture returns the output as a string file. 
In the case where I say the command is not working i see empty string as an output

Comment: Are you really sure? Do you get a different output when you run the command from commandline

Comment: Also, can you explain more about _But the command is not executing properly_. What's exactly happening? What output are you getting?

Comment: How are you executing the commands on the remote Linux machine? Are you using Java's `ProcessBuilder` on the remote machine? (Also, are you satisfied with your security for executing arbitrary commands provided from a different machine?)

Comment: | is intepreted by shell. Does your program deals with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pipe character is a "shell thing" - never going to work within the command executed by a single process.

Consider connecting the output stream of the first command to the input stream of a separate process for the second command.